# How can I determine if a field has leading zeroes in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a varchar field on a table and I need to know if there is a way to know if it starts with a given number of zeroes.

Do I have to use variables or if-else?

Comment: Exactly that amount of leading zeroes and no more than that or just starts with X leading zeroes and may have others after?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `LEFT` to get leading text and compare with zeros string:

```
DECLARE @number INT = 3;

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE LEFT(column_name, @number) = REPLICATE('0', @number)
-- AND SUBSTRING(col, @number+1,1) <> '0'; If you need exact number of leading zeros
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407413)**</kbd>

Or when you need a flag:

```
SELECT *,
  [has_3_leading_zeros] = CASE 
                            WHEN LEFT(column_name, @number) = REPLICATE('0', @number) 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM your_table;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407417)**</kbd>

Another way is to use `LIKE` (this solution is SARG-able and should have better performance if column has index):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE col LIKE REPLICATE('0', @number) + '%'
```